# DRF GnericViewset not accepting json data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm usig `Django 2.x` and `Django REST Framework`.

I have a viewset defined like

```
class UserSettingViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                         mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                         mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                         viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = UserSettingSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, AdminAuthenticationPermission)

    def get_object(self):
        user_setting = UserSetting.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return user_setting

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = UserSetting.objects.filter(
            user=self.request.user
        )

        return queryset

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        iso3 = request.POST.get('country', None)

        if iso3 is None or not iso3:
            raise ValidationError({'country': 'Country iso3 is required'})

        try:
            country = Country.objects.get(iso3=iso3.upper())
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError({'country': 'Country does not exists'})

        user_setting = UserSetting.objects.get(user=request.user)

        user_setting.country = country
        user_setting.save()

        return super(UserSettingViewSet, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

When I call `update` from `Angular` it is not accepting form data and gives the error

```
{'country': 'Country iso3 is required'}
```

**While sending data as **form-data** from postman is working fine.**

The header of the Angular request is

[image]

while that of Postman is

[image]

**How to setup Django to accept json data in PUT?**

Comment: You wouldn't call `update` from Angular. You would have to make a put request like your curl script does.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing the same. Same URL is there in angular.

Comment: What does your angular code look like? Can you get post man to send the formdata a json? If so what happens?

Comment: sending form-data in postman as JSON is giving the same error as that of Angular.

Comment: And that error is?

Comment: `{'country': 'Country iso3 is required'}`

Comment: Maybe your json is malformed.

Comment: You can see the **Request Payload** in the browser's screenshot. The data seems to be valid.

Comment: You should run your server in a debugger and examine the `request` object in your update method.

Comment: I examined the request in Django by printing `print(request.POST)` but it prints blank dictionary when data is sent in JSON format.

Comment: how about `print(request)`? or `print(request.data)`?

Comment: Thanks, Got it solved by replacing `POST` with `data` in `update()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `request.data` instead of `request.POST` in your update method.